# How do I use the new Twilio PHP API version (twilio-php-5.0.0-RC7)?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

Please can someone explain to me how I can convert this code to work with the new Twilio PHP API version available to download on GitHub (twilio-php-5.0.0-RC7)?

```
<?php
    // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
    require_once('twilio/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

    // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
    $sid = "";
    $token = "";
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

    $messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        'To' => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
    ));

    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "<tr><td class=\"text-center\">" . $message->from . "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" . $message->date_sent . "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" . $message->body . "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

There is no longer a `twilio/Services/Twilio.php` file to include and I can't see anything of a similar name and also the documentation doesn't seem to have been updated with a similar example to the above as far as I can see.

Comment: Can you post a link for the download you're talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/releases

Answer (score 1):

[Here are the quickstart instructions for 5.0.0-RC7](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/tree/5.0.0-RC7). You would then set up the Twilio client object like this:

`$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);` as seen in the [docs for next gen installation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php#installation-nextgen).

So you don't need to include `Services/Twilio.php` with this version.

Comment: I'm not using Composer.

Comment: That's fine. It's still a different file to include ([here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/5.0.0-RC7/Twilio/Rest/Client.php)), because `Services/Twilio.php` doesn't exist.